# Unable to restrict user from built in SQL Server Functions

Tags: sql-server, security, permissions

We have a SQL Server (Standard) database with a user whom we are attempting to restrict permissions to only CRUD Operations to certain tables (CREATE, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE) and only allow connect permissions. However, the user still has access to all of the system functions. While some of these are required, we want to restrict users from using some of these functions. For example; host_id(), Db_Id(), etc.

We have the following configurations so far:

### At Server Level

#### Server Login - ServerLogin1

- Specific SQL Server Login
- Roles: ServerRole1 and public
- User mapping: to Database1 as DbUser1 with memberships to DbRole1 and public
- Securables:: TSQL Default TCP - GRANT connect

#### Server Role - ServerRole1

- Securables: TSQL Default TCP - GRANT connect
- Securables: Server - GRANT connect SQL

### At Database Level

#### Database Role - DbRole1

- Securables: sysb schema - DENY - Create Sequence, Delete, Execute, Insert, References, Select, Update, View Change Tracking, View Definition
- Securables: All sys views - DEBY - Select
- Securables: All our DB tables - GRANT - Delete, Insert, Select, Update

#### Database User - DbUser1

- Only has DbRole1 assigned
- Securables: on sys schema - DENY - Delete, Insert, Select, Update

However, we can't seem to find a way to restrict the user from using some of the system functions. How do we deny these permissions?

Comment: What could possibly be the security issue with `host_id()` or `Db_Id()`? And you shouldn't need to `DENY`, just create a role that has only the `GRANT` you need and put the user in that

Comment: We are using this SQL User to connect to the database via an application and at the moment we are unable to restrict some of the SQL Server built-in functions via the application. We are working on this, but need an interim solution. We have created a specific role, but when creating a user, the user automatically gets the public role and the public role allows built-in functions like host_id() and Db_Id(()

Comment: I still don't get why you would ever want to do this (so what if user accesses their own `host_id` or `db_id`? They know that already.) But have you tried `DENY VIEW SERVER STATE TO DBRole1` and `DENY VIEW DATABASE STATE TO DBRole1`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to restrict the use of built-in functions. There was a failed attempt at implementing a system to handle such restrictions in SQL Server 2019 (named "[feature restrictions](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/9e0fa238-8025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0)"), but fortunately that never made it out of beta / CTP (fortunate because it could not accomplish its goal of preventing certain types of activity that could be accomplished via different built-in functions and/or language constructs).

Nor is it even possible to restrict a session from seeing its own data. Meaning, not only can you not restrict `DB_ID()`, you can't even prevent rows that the login has access to from `sys.databases`. The documentation for [DB_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/db-id-transact-sql#permissions) even states:

> ### Permissions
>
> ... The database to which the caller connects will always appear in **sys.databases**.